# Adding logfile command puts script on the loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I'm trying to create logfile for output/terminal files of a script. 
Why is script going for the loop?

Script is used for remotely changing passwords over ssh using imported .txt file with list of addresses. Script is working fine until I add line for logging at the end after DONE:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the username for which you want to change the password"

read USER

sleep 2

echo "Enter the password that you would like to set for $USER"

read PASSWORD

sleep 2

echo "Enter the file name that contains a list of servers. Ex: ip.txt"

read FILE

sleep 2

for HOST in $(cat $FILE)

do 

ssh root@$HOST  "echo $'$PASSWORD\n$PASSWORD' | passwd $USER"

done
```

I tried adding following log creating commands:

```
/root/passwordchange.sh | tee -a /root/output.log

logsave -a /root/output.log /root/passwordchange.sh

/root/passwordchange.sh >> /root/output.log
```

Adding logging line is creating loop for entire program instead of closing it.
I need to sigkill script to end the process.

Output file is created just as normal with all the information provided.

It is my first question here on stack, thank you from advance for all answers